# Setting cookies from webapp. Just won't work

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-app-engine, web-applications, cookies

Been banging my head against the well on this issue for a few hours. I just can't get cookies set properly. The cookie that I am setting never seems to get saved or sent back properly.

The situation is that the cookie:

- Does get sent back when sending the exact same request,
- Does not get sent back when sending a request with a different path.
- Does not seem persist when the browser is re-started
- Does not show up in the Chrome developer tools "Resources" area.

**Server:** "webapp" on "google app engine"

**Client:** Chrome browser, Javascript, jQuery, Ajax calls

Using the following ajax to log the user in, this should set a cookie with a "token":

```
$.ajax({
    type:   'POST',
    url:    '/rest/login/',
    data: JSON.stringify({username:username, password: password}),
    error: function(jqXHR, status, errorThrown){...},
    success: function(data, status, jqXHR){...}
});
```

This produces the following headers [larger pic](http://s3.amazonaws.com/bsldm/public_files/so_cookies_01.gif):

[image]

The server is running webapp on google app engine, this is how it sets the cookie:

```
w_self.response.set_status(200)
#     Put the token in the cookies. "str()" is used because without it, there is a unicode error
w_self.response.headers.add_header(str('Set-Cookie'), str('token=%s; max_age=360;' % token))
#     The user
r_object['user'] = the_user
# Respond
w_self.response.out.write(json.dumps(r_object))
```

If this page is requested again, the cookie IS sent back to the server [larger pic](http://s3.amazonaws.com/bsldm/public_files/so_cookies_02.gif):

[image]

But does not appear to be saved anywhere because I can never find it when exploring cookies in the developer tools [larger pic](http://s3.amazonaws.com/bsldm/public_files/so_cookies_03.gif):

[image]

It also is not sent when requesting a resource who's path is not exactly the same ('logout' instead of 'login':

```
$.ajax({
    type:   'POST',
    url:    '/rest/logout/',
    data: JSON.stringify({something:'else'}),
    error: function(jqXHR, status, errorThrown){...},
    success: function(data, status, jqXHR){...}
});
```

This is what the request looked like:

[larger pic](http://s3.amazonaws.com/bsldm/public_files/so_cookies_04.gif):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why setting the headers isn't working, maybe you could try using the set cookie method:

```
# Saves a cookie in the client.
response.set_cookie('some_key', 'value', max_age=360, path='/',
                    domain='example.org', secure=True)
```

http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/response.html#setting-cookies

Here's the source for the `set_cookie` method:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/lib/webob_1_1_1/webob/response.py#616

Answer (score 1):

If you don't set a path, then the default is to only send it back on the path that set it, as you're seeing.

I also think it's also meant to be Max-Age rather than max_age as you have it, but regardless the response objects that webapp2 give you have a [set_cookie method](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/response.html#setting-cookies) though - I'm sure that will do it all properly.